# How to create a new variable with a existing variable in R?

Tags: r

I would like to create a new variable called `x` in my datasheet. When there is a 1 or 2 coded on `coi_cf` i need the value 1 on the new variable `x` and when there is a 0, 99 or `NA` coded on `coi_cf` I need a 0 on the new variable x.

[image: Data]

Comment: thank for your answer!

`data$x <- ifelse(($coi_cf == 1 | data$coi_cf == 2), 1, 0)`

I tried it with this code, but then I have an NA on x for every NA on coi_cf. Thats not a really a Problem but if there is an easy way to get a 0 for every NA on coi_cf that would be nice.

Comment: Please remove the typos. Look at your result and on that provided by my answer!

Comment: solved it with this code: `data$x <- ifelse ((data$coi_cf == 0 | data$coi_cf == 99 | is.na(data$coi_cf)), 0, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(coi_cf==1 | coi_cf == 2 ~ 1,
                       TRUE ~ 0))
```

```
   coi_cf coi_aufc coi_flafc coi_ra coi_flara x
1      99        0         0      1         1 0
2      99       99        NA      1         3 0
3      99       99        NA      1         3 0
4       0        4         2      1         4 0
5       0        2         4     99        99 0
6      99        4         3      1         3 0
7      99        0         0      0         0 0
8      NA        0        NA     99        NA 0
9      NA        0         0      1         3 0
10      0        0        NA      0        NA 0
11     NA        0        NA      1         3 0
12     NA        0        NA      1         3 0
13     NA        0        NA      1         3 0
14     NA        0        NA      0        NA 0
```

data:

```
structure(list(coi_cf = c(99L, 99L, 99L, 0L, 0L, 99L, 99L, NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA), coi_aufc = c(0L, 99L, 99L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), coi_flafc = c(0L, NA, NA, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), coi_ra = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 99L, 1L, 0L, 99L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), coi_flara = c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 99L, 3L, 0L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But how do I get this new variable into the datafile?

Comment: What do you mean with datafile. you should have a dataframe here it is `df`

Answer (score 0):

I might be overengineering this a little, but in case you anticipate a lot of values being replaced and want to avoid deep-nesting if-conditions, consider building a "replacement table" (named *rtable* below) and joining it to your original table (which I'll simply call "*df*").

```
rtable <- data.frame(coi_cf=c(0,1,2,99,NA), x=c(0,1,1,0,0))
```

Using the dplyr package:

```
newtable <- left_join(df, rtable, by="coi_cf")
```